# Rails: Can I deposit other validations in a custom validator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-3.1, customvalidator, custom-validators

I have a custom validator, which extends ActiveModel::EachValidator.

I want to set dynamic validations in the validates_each-Method dependent on the record.
For instance for one record I need a presence-Validator, and for another record I need a length-Validator.

How can I "append" to this record this dynamic validation?